# Find element position inside iframe having its Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am using the below to get its position away from the Top

```
var posTop = document.getElementById('elementId').getBoundingClientRect().top 
- document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

How is it possible to get its **position** if the **element is inside an iframe** and the iframe is **not in the same domaine**?

Comment: If [you can control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) the other page, otherwise not possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can access to other iframe just if the other domain accepted cross-origin.
so, if it's not your domain, you probably need to ask them to allow that, if possible

Comment: I tried to allow the cross-origin but didn't work for me. Can you provide a simple example ?